# MySQL: How to search from two fields?

Tags: mysql, search

I have a table called optima with a few fields and I need to make a query that will return me results where field1 = `a` and field2 = `b`.

Table for example

```
F1 F2
_____
a  z
v  a
a  b
b  a
```

result must be:

```
a  b
```

I was trying to make query like

```
SELECT * FROM `optima` WHERE `F1` LIKE 'a' AND `F2` LIKE 'b';
```

but it returns me nothing.

Comment: You seriously need to learn SQL basics.

Comment: What are the column types (and length) of F1 and F2?

Comment: Backticks or back quotes are occasionally necessary, but you should avoid them where they are not.  The table name does not need backticks; the only reason the column names might need backticks are because they are in upper-case and were enclosed in backticks when the table was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an exact match, use the `=` operator, e.g.:

```
select *
from `optima`
where `F1` = 'a' and `F2` = 'b';
```

Comment: Do you have backtickitis or something?

Comment: I think in this case `LIKE` is more exact, since it performs comparison character by character and considers trailing spaces. Though, `=` might be better since trailing spaces will be ignored, which might be the issue.

Comment: and what if i need to search something like that: `a, b%` in table with `a, bc`? so just use `like`, not `=`?

Comment: @SergiiRechmp select * from `optima` where `F1` = 'a' and `F2` like 'b%';